# Acumatica mobile - Field change not committing on action press

Tags: c#, acumatica

On my mobile app page I have a simple text field for a location. Beneath the field is a button. When the button gets pressed, it navigates to a new container, and the value from this text box is supposed to be copied over to a different text box in the container. If I enter a value in the text box, click out of the field, and then press the button, the change is committed to the cache, and I can access the new value in my code. However, if I enter a value in the text box and press the button without clicking out of the text box, the change is not committed to the cache so I can't access the new value.

The strange thing is that if I mimic these steps in the web browser, no matter what, the change is always committed to the cache.

I have the "CommitChanges" property set to True for the button and the field on the web page, but that's not a possibility in the mobile app page.

Is there any way I can force the page to commit the changes for this field when I run the action? I've tried refreshing the view and raising the field updated event, but neither worked.

This is how my action is declared in my msd file.

```
add recordAction "RedirectLocationMobileFrom"{
    behavior = Record
    Redirect = True
    RedirectToContainer = "CreateNewAddress"
    DisplayName = "Create Location from this address"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I enter a value in the text box, click out of the field, and then
>   press the button, the change is committed to the cache, and I can
>   access the new value in my code. However, if I enter a value in the
>   text box and press the button without clicking out of the text box,
>   the change is not committed to the cache so I can't access the new
>   value.

This is the description of a bug caused by UI event handlers. I've noticed it in the desktop browser website too. Actions can get away with it by calling Save explicitly before doing their thing. Unfortunately I don't know of a workaround for mobile, consider filling in a bug report.

The proper fix would be better handling of focus events. There is only a single UI element focused at all time. When you give focus to another element the currently focused one receives a lost focus event. This is the event that triggers the CommitChanges. I suspect the bug is that clicking on the button doesn't remove focus from the text box thus never invoking lost focus event and preventing CommmitChanges.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to manually trigger the lost focus event via code? I'm pretty comfortable with customization projects and manipulating the framework.

Comment: RaiseFieldUpdated method will do similar operation but I believe the issue is UI related. If that's the case, value entered in UI is lost and inaccessible from the BLC graph.